# Binding error using ApplicationBarButtonCommand and DelegateCommand

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, mvvm, prism

I hav simple WP7 application, I am trying to bind to the ApplicationBarButtonCommand using Prism DelegateCommand.

The code is below.

XAML:

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar.share.rest.png" Text="Add"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>

<wi:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <i:ApplicationBarButtonCommand ButtonText="Add" CommandBinding="{Binding SaveMessageCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                                   CommandParameterBinding="{Binding CurrentUser.Id}"/>
</wi:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

ViewModel:

public ICommand SaveMessageCommand { get; private set; }

```
public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService, INavigationService navigationService)
{
     //Some initialization goes here

     SaveMessageCommand = new DelegateCommand<int>(OnSaveMessage);
}

private void OnSaveMessage(int userId)
{
     if (_navigationService != null)
     {
        // TODO : change 0 to real current user id
        _navigationService.NavigateTo(new Uri(string.Format(ViewModelLocator.CreateNewMessageUrl, userId),
                    UriKind.Relative));
     }
}
```

User class:

```
public class User : BaseModel
{
    private int _id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _id)
            {
                return;
            }

            _id = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }
 }
```

When I run application I have Data Error

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 'MS.Internal.Data.DynamicValueConverter' converter failed to convert value 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands.DelegateCommand`1[System.Int32]' (type 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands.DelegateCommand`1[System.Int32]'); BindingExpression: Path='SaveMessageCommand' DataItem='WindowsPhone_Application.ViewModel.MainViewModel' (HashCode=75877085); target element is 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity.ApplicationBarButtonCommand' (Name='null'); target property is 'CommandBinding' (type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding').. System.InvalidOperationException: Can't convert type Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands.DelegateCommand`1[System.Int32] to type System.Windows.Data.Binding.
```

Any ideas what can cause the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue, the problem was with System.Windows.Interactivity, just put the reference to another version, which is included with the prism